# wait 5 seconds to a progress bar be invisible in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, progress-bar, wait

I have a progress bar set initially INVISIBLE.after clicking a button i want the bar to appear for 5 seconds than disappear. I'm using Thread.sleep(5000) but nothing happen

```
public void dec(View v) throws InterruptedException{
ProgressBar pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.bar);
pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Thread.sleep(5000);
pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you're freezing the UI thread by doing that, so one approach would be to create a new Thread, and use a Handler to post back to the UI thread, so that it doesn't get clogged up and can continue drawing.

For instance:

```
final ProgressBar pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.bar); // Final so we can access it from the other thread
pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// Create a Handler instance on the main thread
Handler handler = new Handler();

// Create and start a new Thread
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
         try{
             Thread.sleep(5000);
         }
         catch (Exception e) { } // Just catch the InterruptedException

         // Now we use the Handler to post back to the main thread
         handler.post(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
               // Set the View's visibility back on the main UI Thread 
               pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

And, as Chris suggested below, you should remove any pending messages from the Handler when the Activity is closing to avoid running into an IllegalStateException when trying to run the posted message/Runnable in an Activity that no longer exists:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: make sure you check that you remove the callbacks from the handler in the activities onStop

Comment: also, why would you just not call handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()). Create the seperate thread adds a lot of overhead and more stuff to manage.

Comment: I was thinking of using postDelayed, but it doesn't really do much to explain threading and the blocking of the UI that he is experiencing. Sure, I could throw the short snippet at him, but that's not going to help in the long run. As for removing the callback, yes, you should, and I'm about to update the post for ya~

Comment: Yes, but you did provide some code using his example but didn't suggest removing the thread as it is not needed anymore with the handler.  Then he can figure out the rest.

Comment: You dont need to sleep the current thread and you dont need a thread when you use a handler. By having the separate thread in your example, your opening the door for the OP to have more issues.  I'm not saying that code snippets need to be exact or 100% complete, but don't steer the guy down a bad path.

Comment: "You dont need to sleep the current thread and you dont need a thread when you use a handler" -- Without using postDelayed, how could you possibly try to say that doesn't need to be done in a separate thread if he's trying to sleep for 5 seconds? And I would love to hear how you would argue that your suggestion is beneficial in explaining the issue at hand (which is threading) in any way, and would also love to hear your explanation of how I'm "steering the guy down a bad path." Please, enlighten me.

Comment: Having a thread is creating unneeded overhead for his case. Plus, now he has to manage a Thread and a handler. Your code should not post to the handler if the thread was interrupted.  You had already explained what was happening with the UI blocking so why not only use the handler in your example.  Your not adding to the solution by additionally including a separate thread.  Anyways, no point in arguing over an answer where the OP doesn't give credit for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a runnable and running it on the uithread with `runOnUiThread(new Runnable());`?

then do the same Thread.sleep(5000);

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html